# Reading the Quran from the beginning

Tags: halal-haram

I had finished half the Quran before Ramadan 2016.Is it okay if I restart from the beginning? Or should I continue ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do whatever you want. If you want to continue, then continue; if you want to restart, then do it.